# Find a substring in a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a columns 'status'.
I would replace the value of status column by 1 if the value of status contains the word "Won" otherwise it replace it by 0.

I tried something like this:

```
s = oppty_oppline['status']
if s.find("Won") == -1:
       oppty_oppline['status']=0
else:
        oppty_oppline['status']=1
```

But I got this error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7d82ff1c0e85> in <module>()
      1 s = oppty_oppline['status']
----> 2 if s.contains("Won") == -1:
      3        oppty_oppline['status']=0
      4 else:
      5         oppty_oppline['status']=1

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]
-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask and map `True/False` to `1/0` by casting to integer:

```
oppty_oppline['status'] = oppty_oppline['status'].str.contains('Won').astype(int)
```

Or using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
oppty_oppline['status'] = np.where(oppty_oppline['status'].str.contains('Won'), 0, 1)
```